# Hi I am trying to make a post request to my json server but getting unexpected results

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, components, state

I am trying to set up my application so that I can create a new contact conditionally depending on if there is already a user with that same name. I am using axios to make a post request in my app once a new contact gets created, for some reason , my app is adding 4 copies of the entered contact to my server. In addition to this, my conditional statement is still adding the contact to the server 4 times regardless if the name already exists in the list of contacts(aka persons state array). Ideally, I would like to add one contact not four copies and I only want to add that contact if the name does not already exist in my persons state

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [disabledState, setDisabledState] = useState(false);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]);
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState("");

 useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3004/persons").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setPersons(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const setQuery = (e) => {
    setNewName(e.target.value);
    setDisabledState(false);
  };

  const setSearch = (e) => {
    setSearchValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const numberChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setNumber(e.target.value);
  };


  const addContact = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newContact = {
      name: newName,
      number: number,
    };

    setNewName("");
    setNumber("");
    console.log(searchValue);
    persons.map((person) => {
      if (person.name === newName) {
        alert(`${newName} is already added to the phonebook`);
        setDisabledState(true);
      } else {
        console.log("does not exist");
        axios
          .post("http://localhost:3004/persons", newContact)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            // setPersons(persons.concat(response.data));
          });
      }
    });
  };

  const removeContact = (person) => {
    console.log("deleted");
    console.log(person);
    console.log(persons);
    let filtered = persons.filter((c) => c !== person);
    setPersons(filtered);
  };


return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form
        handleSearch={setSearch}
        handleFormChange={setQuery}
        addContact={addContact}
        value={newName}
        disabledValue={disabledState}
        placeholder={"Enter name"}
        handleNumberChange={numberChange}
        searchValue={searchValue}
      />
      <Contacts contacts={showingContacts} removeContact={removeContact} />
     
    </div>
  );


}
```

db.json

```
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "name": "Arto Hellas",
      "number": "040-123456",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      "number": "39-44-5323523",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Dan Abramov",
      "number": "12-43-234345",
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "Mary Poppendieck",
      "number": "39-23-6423122",
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "matt",
      "number": "0",
      "id": 5
    }
   
  ]
}
```

Contacts.js

```
import React from "react";

function Contacts(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Numbers</h1>
      <ul>
        {props.contacts.map((person) => (
          <div
            style={{
              border: "2px solid grey",
              margin: "3%",
              padding: "2%",
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            <li style={{ listStyleType: "none" }} key={person.id}>
              Name: {person.name}, Number: {person.number}{" "}
            </li>
            <button onClick={() => props.removeContact(person)}>x</button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Contacts;
```

Form.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Form(props) {
  return <div>
      <h1>PhoneBook</h1>
      <input placeholder='Search' value={props.searchValue} onChange={props.handleSearch}/>
 <form onSubmit={props.addContact} style={{margin: '1%'}}>
        <input value={props.value} onChange={props.handleFormChange} placeholder={props.placeholder} />
        <input   onChange={props.handleNumberChange} placeholder='Enter Number' />

        <button type="submit" disabled={props.disabledValue}>save</button>
      </form> 
   
  </div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should avoid using `map` in your `addContact` to find duplicates, it causes multiple api calls, instead use `find` method:

```
const duplicateContact = persons.find(person => person.name === newName)
if(duplicateContact) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```